# IE8 truncates json string to 1986 characters

Tags: json, internet-explorer

I'm using Ext.util.json.encode to encode the column model from a jqgrid, and passing that as the query string. It's long, but it works in Chrome/Firefox. In IE8, I see that the last half of the last column is truncated. If the last column is:

> {"name":"Base","index":"GEOGRAPHIC_LOCATION","width":46,"type":"STRING","title":true,"hidden":false,"widthOrg":40,"resizable":true,"sortable":true}]

in IE, only up to

> {"name":"Base","index":"GEOGRAPHIC_LOCATION","width"

is returned and the last 96 characters are cut off, for a total of 1986 characters as opposed to 2085.

I'm stumped. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427), there is a 2083 character limit on the entire URL; that includes not only the query string, but the rest of the URL as well.

This may have been relaxed in IE9- see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721034/how-long-an-url-can-internet-explorer-9-take) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url) for more info.

Comment: thanks - I guess my googling skills were sub-par on this one. I went ahead and re-worked it to not pass the query string - probably a better idea anyway. Thanks.