# What is the best way to represent a URL in a Django model?

Tags: django

I was thinking something like this:

```
url = models.CharField(max_length=2047)
```

Is there a solution that would be more efficient for the ORM / SQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [URLField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#urlfield) but it's just a subclass of [CharField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.CharField) and thus defaults to 200 characters.

However [IE8](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q208427/) & [9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721034/how-long-an-url-can-internet-explorer-9-take)'s limit for URL length is 2083 chars, Firefox, Opera, and Safari can handle at least 80,000 chars. I doubt you'll ever see a URL that long without a bunch of get data (like `&whatever=1&whatelse=2...`)

Comment: The browsers are 1 piece of that.  The other is the servers.  Here is a link to a recent change for asp.Net http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4#0.2__Toc253429244.  So, 200 is probably fine for 99% of inputs that you will get.  If you need to change it, then use the max_length option.

Comment: I agree. It's nice to see the upper limit though.

Answer (score 0):

Use URLField (or IPAddressField) for this. It is transformed to string by Django. [URLField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#urlfield)