# How to configure the web.config to allow requests of any length

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, web-config, query-string

I am building a site in which i would like to create a file client side from the value of a textarea element.

I have the code in place to do this, but i am getting this error

> HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found The request filtering module is
>   configured to deny a request where the query string is too long.

Is there a way to override this so that I am able to process requests of any size?

If not, is there a way to generate files client side without using the filesystem/active x object?

thanks

Comment: What you want to consider is that even though the query string length may be configurable for IIS or your application, there is an HTTP standard for URL length. Since you're using a query string you're passing values as part of the URL. The max URL character length is 2000 characters. If your values are going to be lengthy strings, it would be best to POST the values rather than passing them in the query string.

Comment: Agree with Jlafay. It is a best Practice to POST the values when you have more than 2-3 simple parameters. and when you use query string be sure to encrypt them.

Answer (score 301, accepted):

Add the following to your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxQueryString="32768"/>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

See:

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits

**Updated to reflect comments.**

[requestLimits Element for requestFiltering [IIS Settings Schema]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689462%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

You may have to add the following in your web.config as well

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxQueryStringLength="32768" maxUrlLength="65536"/>
</system.web>
```

See: [httpRuntime Element (ASP.NET Settings Schema)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Of course the numbers (32768 and 65536) in the config settings above are just examples.  You don't have to use those exact values.

Comment: That alone was not enough for me. I had to also add this to the system.web section:     <httpRuntime maxQueryStringLength="8192"/>

Comment: nnn is the maximum string length that you'd like to allow, e.g. 32768

Comment: not working see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31624710/mvc-website-bad-request-invalid-url-http-error-400-the-request-url-is-inval

Comment: I tried each one individually, setting the security node under system.webServer and then removing and just adding the attributes to the httpRuntime node.  I definitely needed both to work.  Many thanks!

Comment: An update for those of us using ASP.Net Core 1.1 (which doesn't even have a Web.config anymore) would be highly appreciated!  :D

Comment: Note: the **<httpRuntime>** tag goes under **<system.web>**:            
<system.web><httpRuntime maxQueryStringLength="32768" maxUrlLength="65536"/></system.web>

Comment: I'm using IIS 8.5 and this was not working for me.  From other answer and comments here I think this is a fix for IIS 7 only.  If that is the case maybe the answer should be updated to reflect that in bold?

Comment: If you are looking for a solution to IIS 8.5 see my answer which also uses the gui and has images.

Answer (score 36):

In my case ( Visual Studio 2012 / IIS Express / ASP.NET MVC 4 app / .Net Framework 4.5 ) what really worked after 30 minutes of trial and error was setting the `maxQueryStringLength` property in the `<httpRuntime>` tag:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxQueryStringLength="10240" enable="true" />
```

`maxQueryStringLength` defaults to `2048`.

More about it here:

[Expanding the Range of Allowable URLs](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4#0.2__Toc253429244)

---

I tried setting it in `<system.webServer>` as [@MattVarblow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11636484/114029) suggests, but it didn't work... and this is because I'm using IIS Express (based on IIS 8) on my dev machine with Windows 8.

When I deployed my app to the production environment (Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7), IE 10 started returning 404 errors in AJAX requests with long query strings. Then I thought that the problem was related to the query string and tried @MattVarblow's answer. It just worked on IIS 7. :)

Comment: For me it was the enable="true" that made the magic happen :)

Answer (score 17):

If you run into this issue when running an IIS 8.5 web server you can use the following method.

First, find the **"Request Filtering"** module in the IIS site you are working on, then double click it...

[image]

Next, you need to right click in the white area shown below then click the context menu option called **"Edit Feature Settings"**.

[image]

Then the last thing to do is change the **"Maximum query string (Bytes)"** value from **2048** to something more appropriate such as **5000** for your needs.

[image]

Comment: thanks man! you are life saver!

Answer (score 6):

Something else to check: if your site is using MVC, this can happen if you added [Authorize] to your login controller class. It can't access the login method because it's not authorized so it redirects to the login method --> boom.

Comment: Thanks! I experienced this problem because I moved the Menu/Navigation to a partial view and another Controller which didn't allow anonymous connections.

Comment: Another case where the error message, although true, bears no relation to the actual problem.

Comment: Also check out the project properties as it could be that the Windows Authentication is “Enabled” and the Anonymous Authentication is Disabled”. Pls check out this detailed article - [Error (Visual Studio 2013, MVC5): The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/805682/Error-The-request-filtering-module-query-string-is)

Answer (score 2):

**It will also  generate error when you pass large string in  ajax call parameter.**

so for that alway use type post in  ajax will resolve **your issue 100%**  and no  need to set the length in web.config.

**//  var UserId= array of 1000 userids**

```
$.ajax({
        global: false,
        url: SitePath + "/User/getAussizzMembersData",
        "data": { UserIds: UserId},
        "type": "POST",
        "dataType": "JSON"
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue trying to deploy an ASP Web Application to IIS 8. To fix it I did as Matt and Leniel suggested above. But also had to configure the Authentication setting of my site to enable Anonymous Authentication. And that Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add [AllowAnonymous] to the ActionResult functions in my login page because the user was not authenticated yet.

Answer (score 0):

If your website is using authentication, but you don't have the correct authentication method set up in IIS (e.g. Basic, Forms etc..) then the browser will be getting stuck in a redirect loop.  This causes the redirect url to get longer and longer until it explodes.

Comment: How can one fix it?

Comment: @Yster You need to set your authentication method to be one that is set up correctly.  (There will be the option somewhere in the quagmire of IIS settings and options).

Answer (score 0):

For someone who experiences this while running the apps from Visual Studio, while using IIS Express, first you have to locate the **applicationhost.config** file being used by the application. See the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/41553876/1849880 on how to locate the **applicationhost.config** file. Then, you can change the *maxQueryString* value as explained above.

Answer (score -1):

> HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found The request filtering module is
>   configured to deny a request where the query string is too long.

To resolve this problem, check in the source code whether the `Form` tag has a property `method` is get/set state.

If so, the `method` property should be removed.