# Windows Azure WebSites maxQueryStringLength

Tags: azure, datatables

I'm trying to use jquery dataTables with a few extras on Azure Websites.  It generates a sizeable query string (2121 characters in testing).  This returns a bad code on Azure websites (The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.).

To get it working locally I edited the web.config with this:

```
<httpRuntime maxQueryStringLength="4000" maxUrlLength="4000"/>
```

(I believe only the maxQueryStringLength is really needed).

Anyway, all is fine locally and on another server but on WA Web Sites I can't get it working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try customizing [IIS Request Filtering parameters](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering).
I suspect you're using *Cassini* (Visual Studio development server) to develop locally.

Limitations related to Query String and/or URL max lengths occur at two levels on Azure Websites (or any IIS environments) :

- *ASP.NET Runtime* : These limits are lifted using the `httpRuntime` node and its associated attributes
- *IIS Requests Filtering* module : IIS also applies its own filtering rules regarding URL and Query String length, even before the request is processed by the ASP.NET Runtime. By default, the maximum allowed length for a query string is 2048 (see [here](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits)). You should set the appropriate values in your `Web.config`, under the `requestLimits` subnodes, eg :

  ```
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxQueryString="4096"/>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  ```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636386/how-to-configure-the-web-config-to-allow-requests-of-any-length)