# How to increase URL query string length in Php on Azure?

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service, query-string

I'm using jQuery data table with more than 20 columns on Azure Web app so a length of URL query string is going more than 2048 and I'm getting an error which says "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

I referred  below links: 
 [Windows Azure WebSites maxQueryStringLength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026142/windows-azure-websites-maxquerystringlength)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-php-configure

but I'm not getting any solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use HTTP `POST` requests to send larger amounts of data, not `GET`.

Comment: thank you @cweiske for an answer. But is there any configuration for query string length on Azure?