# HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found while exporting in crystal report in mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, crystal-reports

Need on help this issue.

I am able to view the report(crystal report) in ASP.NET mvc (aspx view) without any error

But when I export the report to either PDF or other format, the

**HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found**

**The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long.**

is appearing

Comment: See if this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636386/how-to-configure-the-web-config-to-allow-requests-of-any-length

Comment: its generating some other error .The length of the query string for this request exceeds the configured maxQueryStringLength value.

Comment: Try increasing the value of maxQueryStringLength in web.config