# HTTP Error 404.15 -Not Found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5

The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long.

I am having above error, and I have been trying almost everything but no luck

My Project is MVC4 on Visual Studio 2013

things I have made sure are correct and tried.

- There is no [Authorize] Attr on my classes with [AllowAnonymous] Attr.
- I have added maxQueryStringLength="32768" maxUrlLength="65536" to  in my config file
- I have added 
      -->
- I have [AllowAnonymous] attr on my log on Actions in my controller.
- I have no problem when I run the application in debug mode or without debug mode on Visual Studio.
- here is my rout config 
  routes.MapRoute(
              name: "Default",
              url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
              defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
          );
- this is the error I am getting on the web server

[image]

Answer (score 9):

**Insert/Update web.config file as like sample below**

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
       <security>
          <requestFiltering>
             <requestLimits maxQueryString="3000" maxUrl="1000" />
          </requestFiltering>
       </security>
   </system.webServer>
   <system.web>
       <httpRuntime maxQueryStringLength="32768" maxUrlLength="65536"/>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 5):

As the error message tells you

> The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long.

At the screenshot you can clearly see that the `returnUrl` Parameter is huge.

So there are to solutions

1. Clear your `returnUrl` Parameter in your Controller Method `[HttpPost] Login();`
2. Add the following to your `web.config` :

**web.config**

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxQueryString="*"/> <!-- Replace * with any number, which is required -->
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

---

In your case go definitively with Solution 1. It's simply a bug in your Code and easily fixed without touching the IIS or other config files.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636386/how-to-configure-the-web-config-to-allow-requests-of-any-length) for more information about Request Query String Limit.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have added the <system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxQueryString="32768"/>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer> to Web.config but I am getting another error 

 The length of the query string for this request exceeds the configured maxQueryStringLength value.

Comment: @Frank Why? Fixing the Code in your Controller, would be much simpler

Comment: How would you fix this on the controller ? thank you @Smartis

Comment: @Frank In your Controller must be a Method like this `[HttpPost] Login();` which should return a `Action` with the parameter `returnUrl`. Instead of adding every time something to this parameter, clear the value. This should only store the last `returnUrl` value and shouldn't blow up your requested URL.

Comment: I was able to fix this thank you for all of your help.

Answer (score 3):

just modify the web.config
add

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<security>
<requestFiltering>
<requestLimits maxQueryString="30000" maxUrl="10000" />  
</requestFiltering>
</security>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

also add under <system.web>

```
<httpRuntime maxQueryStringLength="32768" maxUrlLength="65536"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have already scaffolding the identity login , just add [AllowAnonymous]     in the page (behind code) login, like this :

[AllowAnonymous]
public class LoginModel : PageModel
{
.......
}

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I replaced GET method with POST and it worked.

Comment: Of course it did. POST has much more space that GET

Answer (score 0):

Put [AllowAnonymous] in the Login Page(for Razor Project like mine) or the View's Controller(for MVC - I imagine).

Perhaps you scaffolded the Login Page, thereby making it subject - as soon as you hit Login button - to your fallback policy* in your Program.cs (now in .NET 6.0, Startup.cs for earlier .NET). Your fallback policy forbids any Page(view) without a policy, and since you have no policy in the login page, as soon as you hit the login it calls that view, and you get the error.  I'm not sure that I understand why it isn't a nice error. Perhaps because it tries a hundred times to put that URL in and therefore it implies that in the 25252525225252522 etc and so forth message.

Luckily I was helped pinpointing the error because my app worked fine logging in and out without the fallback policy, but it was exactly that fallback policy that caused error.

- By fallback policy, I refer to:

  builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
  {
  options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
  .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
  .Build();
  });