# Allow requests of any length per Service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

The answer to  [How to configure the web.config to allow requests of any length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636386/how-to-configure-the-web-config-to-allow-requests-of-any-length) works fine.

Is there a way to change the limit for a specific service?
For example something like

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
     <requestFiltering serviceName="MyService.asmx">//Only for 1 service
         <requestLimits maxQueryString="32768"/>
     </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a *location*  element and setting the settings there seemed to do the trick

```
<location path="MyService.asmx">
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering >
      <requestLimits  maxAllowedContentLength="102400000"/>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

If there is another/better solution feel free to post it