# The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long

Tags: asp.net

the below code is added in web config i got the below error message(please check the below query string).

```
<!--<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>-->
```

if i remove the above authorization code the page is launching.

Requested URL      http://localhost:63547/PreSalesBlog/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FPreSalesBlog%2FAccount%2FLogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FPreSalesBlog%252FAccount%252FLogin%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252FPreSalesBlog%25252FAccount%25252FLogin%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252FPreSalesBlog%2525252FAccount%2525252FLogin%2525253FReturnUrl%2525253D%252525252FPreSalesBlog%252525252FAccount%252525252FLogin%252525253FReturnUrl%252525253D%25252525252FPreSalesBlog%25252525252FAccount%25252525252FLogin%25252525253FReturnUrl%25252525253D%2525252525252FPreSalesBlog%2525252525252FAccount%2525252525252FLogin%2525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525253D%252525252525252FPreSalesBlog%252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252FLogin%252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525253D%25252525252525252FPreSalesBlog%25252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525253D%2525252525252525252FPreSalesBlog%2525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252FPreSalesBlog%252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252FPreSalesBlog%25252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252FPreSalesBlog%2525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252FPreSalesBlog%252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252FPreSalesBlog%25252525252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252FPreSalesBlog%2525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252FPreSalesBlog%252525252525252525252525252525252FLoginPage%252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252525252fPreSalesBlog%25252525252525252525252525252525252fAdminLogin

Comment: if i remove the above authorization code it is launching properly

Comment: Hi, please add additional info as [edit] of your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure the web.config to allow requests of any length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636386/how-to-configure-the-web-config-to-allow-requests-of-any-length)

Comment: fred i have tired the link which you have provided but it is not working

Comment: Looks like a redirect loop. Show the relevant config, routing and authorize attributes.