# Error while sending a long text with angularjs to c# api

Tags: c#, angularjs, api

This is my angularjs

```
$scope.article.update = function (modif,e) {
    $http.put('api/Article', {}, {
        params: {
            iduser: $scope.idutilisateur,
            idTypeArticle: modif.idTypeArticle,
            articleuid: getQueryStringValue("articleuid"),
            creatoruid: getQueryStringValue("creatoruid"),
            articleTitle: modif.articleTitle,
            littleDescrption: modif.littleDescrption,
            bprivate: modif.bprivate,
            articleContent: modif.articleContent
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log("test")
    })
}
```

this is my c# api

```
public void Put(string iduser, string idTypeArticle, string articleuid, string creatoruid, string articleTitle, string littleDescrption, string bprivate, string articleContent= "")
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE_ARTICLE", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iduser", iduser);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idTypeArticle", idTypeArticle);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@articleuid", articleuid);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@creatoruid", creatoruid);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@articleTitle", articleTitle);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@littleDescrption", littleDescrption);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bprivate", bprivate);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bassocieadresse", bassocieadresse);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Configuration", String.IsNullOrEmpty(articleContent) ? null : articleContent);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

when the articleContent is too long I have an error message. Someone have any idea how to resolve my issue. Because the problème is only when the text is too long

**Resolved thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11636484/10863293)**
[image: errormessage]

Comment: This is a 404.15 Error:Query String Too Long. You should change the limit if you need to send that data as params: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits/](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits/)

Comment: The error message in your screenshot is very hard to read but it seems IIS is just informing you the query string is too long.