# Can i trick IE 10 to accept <a> href attribute bigger than 5000 characters?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

Is there any way to trick the browser (IE) to add the `href` attribute, into an `<a>` tag, that have more than 5000 characters? Chrome and Firefox seems to work with long `href` strings.

Comment: why do you have a href that's so long - the more relevant question is probably "what alternatives do I have to <explain what you're currently doing>?"

Comment: You seem to be looking in the wrong direction. Look for POST requests.

Comment: From [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19923997/cant-change-href-attribute-of-an-a-tag-in-ie-10) it seems likely you're trying to embed an xls file as a data-uri (???) - You need to rethink your solution, rather than try and fight the problems with your general approach (e.g. you need to point at a file).

Answer (score 1):

In short no, this is a browser restriction and can vary throughout all the browser variations.

You need to find a different way to achieve what you are trying to do as you shouldn't need to use 5000 chars in a Url.