# web api returns 404

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm currently using asp.net web api for the first time and having problems with `404`s being returned when trying to post to a particular method.

The api works fine but when one of the parameters reaches a certain length a `404` is returned.

The parameter in question is only around 2000 characters in length.

This is the signature for the api method:

```
public Boolean Add(String Source, Int32 CreatedByID, String CreatedBy, 
            String Header, String Body, Boolean IsLive, Boolean IsNotification)
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I'm calling my api with angular if that makes any difference.

Comment: If doing a post, then why not use Add([FormData] YourObject yourObject) and serialize he post data to that object, instead of passing query string params. Sounds like you are not really using an httppost

Comment: Hi Tim, I'm using the $http service in angular and specifying POST as the method. Its strange as it works fine but as soon as one of the parameters gets to a certain length it returns 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The max length for a url is 2000 characters in some browsers so try with less parameters and see if it helps.

Comment: Do you have a source of that? I know you could be right, but it would be nice to see it actually in the answer.

Comment: Hi Christian, I did think that might be the case, but didnt think it would return a 404

Answer (score 1):

A **GREAT** explanation and **CREDIT** goes here: [What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)

Some key points in case the other ever gets lost... I have kept the extracts verbatim" so as not to pretend this is my own work!

### Short answer - de facto limit of 2000 characters

If you keep URLs under 2000 characters, they'll work in virtually any combination of client and server software.

### Longer answer - first, the standards...

[RFC 2616](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html) (Hypertext Transfer Protocol HTTP/1.1) section 3.2.1 says

> The HTTP protocol does not place
>   any a priori limit on the length of
>   a URI. Servers MUST be able to handle
>   the URI of any resource they    serve,
>   and SHOULD be able to handle URIs of
>   unbounded length if they    provide
>   GET-based forms that could generate
>   such URIs. A server    SHOULD return
>   414 (Request-URI Too Long) status if a
>   URI is longer    than the server can
>   handle (see section 10.4.15).
>
> *Note: Servers ought to be cautious
>   about depending on URI lengths
>         above 255 bytes, because some older client or proxy
>         implementations might not properly support these lengths.*

### Internet Explorer's limitations...

[IE8's maximum URL length is 2083 chars](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q208427/), and it seems [IE9 has a similar limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721034/how-long-an-url-can-internet-explorer-9-take).

I've tested IE10 and the address bar will only accept 2083 chars. You can *click* a URL which is longer than this, but the address bar will still only show 2083 characters of this link.